# crystal report viewer 13_0_5 not working in vpn

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

I'm troubleshooting an error a user is having while running reports through crystal reports viewer with run time version of 13.0.5. The crystal report viewer gives me error in allInOne.js file when accessing my application through VPN

when debugging the java script the error shows in the below location

```
return("["+A.map(A.repr,B).join(", ")+"]")},reprString:function(A)**{returnDanaMethodReplace("replace",DanaMethodReplace("replace",DanaMethodReplace("replace",DanaMethodReplace("replace",(DanaMethodReplace("replace",('"'+DanaMethodReplace("replace",A,/(["\\])/g,"\\$1")+'"'),/[\f]/g,"\\f"),/[\b]/g,"\\b"),/[\n]/g,"\\n"),/[\t]/g,"\\t"),/[\r]/g,"\\r"**))},reprNumber:function(A){return A+""},registerJSON:function(B,A,D,C){MochiKit.Base.jsonRegistry.register(B,A,D,C)},evalJSON:function(){return eval(DanaEval("("+arguments[0]+")")
```

Configuration:

- The application is deployed on our network on a server with the
  32bit_13_0_5 run time installed and is located in Qatar.
- The user is accessing our network via VPN from France.
- The user's browser is Internet Explorer 8.

The issue is not been able to reproduce from the machine which is accessing the application through network. Has anyone experienced similar behavior?

Comment: Found a solution for this issue. Just added the space after and before the "return" word in allinOne.js file then it worked. Since there is no space, vpn is added its method like "returnDanaMethodReplace". It should be "return DanaMethodReplace...".  

Original script : "...reprString:function(A){return(..."
Changed script  : "...reprString:function(A){ return (..."